# Prestashop URL making

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, caching

I wanted to switch my prestashop to https. Unfortunately, my website is now adding before every URL this: `http://https//`example.com. If I change in admin Preference -> SEO & URLs domain name for example to google.com, result is still redirection to `http://https//google.com//` so nothing load at all.

I remember I played with .htaccess file, but now everything is back as was before. Also problem may be caused by deleting cache/smarty/cache and cache/smarty/compile folders.

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove your .htaccess file
2- Go to Preference -> SEO & URLs and click on Save button